# Bosh stemcell Ubuntu Ruby, in conflict with /var/vcap/bosh/lib/ruby (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, cloud-foundry, gist, bosh-deployer

I tried to install `gist` tool in Bosh VM

> Synopsis
>          The  gist  gem provides a gist-paste command that you can use from your
>          terminal to upload content to https://gist.github.com/.

version

```
stemcells:
- name: bosh-openstack-kvm-ubuntu-trusty-go_agent
  version: 3232.2
```

Ubuntu package installation and release:

```
# apt-get install gist
# cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS"
# dpkg -l gist
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                   Version                  Architecture             Description
+++-======================================-========================-========================-==================================================================================
ii  gist                                   4.2.0-1                  all                      Upload gists to gist.github.com
```

error message I receive

```
# gist-paste -p mongodb.log*
/var/vcap/bosh/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- gist (LoadError)
        from /var/vcap/bosh/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/bin/gist-paste:7:in `<main>'
```

There is some conflict with Ubuntu provided Ruby and the one from `/var/vcap/bosh/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems`. Any idea howto use the Right ruby gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the gist-paste command as a user other than root, it should work fine. I tested this myself on stemcell 1.3232.0